# Expresiones regulares-Negar caracteres consecutivos

Tags: java, regex, netbeans, java-8, fuentes

Palabras que tengan longitud desde 4 y hasta 7, teniendo como alfabeto {a,b,c}, donde no pueden estar de forma consecutiva bc.

La parte de que no puedan estar de forma consecutiva bc es lo que me está dando problemas :(

Si me pueden ayudar se los agradecería mucho

Comment: tenes que agregar que intentaste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

creo que este debería funcionarte:

```
([ac]|[b](?!c)){4,7}
```

Eso admite cualquier ristra del alfabeto {a,b,c}, siempre y cuando no contenga la ristra 'bc'

Comment: me sirvió, muchas gracias!